# swap radios if selected using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, radio-button

On clicking a radio button in radiogroup2, the selected radio should swap positions with the radio with the id='selectedradio'. fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DCC66/6/ --- updated --- clear view of radio rows and code is swapping but cancelling out http://jsfiddle.net/DCC66/14/

tried this to sort the id issue: http://jsfiddle.net/DCC66/18/

```
$(".radiogroup2 input[type='radio']").on('click', function () {
    $('#radioselected').closest('label').before($(this).closest('label'));
    $(this).closest('label').after($('#radioselected').closest('label'));
    $(this).attr('domaintype', 'radioselected');
    $('radioselected').attr('radioselected', 'domaintype');
});
```

and now this:// swaps once then stops and then just makes the clicked radio disapear. think it needs to add the id="radioselected" to the newly swapped radio. also still not swapping though only replacing radio.

```
$(".radiogroup2 input[type='radio']").on('click', function () 
{
    $('#radioselected').closest('label').replaceWith($(this).closest('label'));
});
```

trying using clone still no luck:

```
$("div.radiogroup2 input[name='domain_ext']").click(function () 
{
    $(this).clone('#radioselected').after(this);
});
```

Original

```
$("div.radiogroup2 input[name='domain_ext']").click(function() 
{ 
    //only if a the radio in radiogroup to are clicked take radio and swap with id='radioselected'
    if  ($(this).prop('checked')) 
    {
        $(this).after('#radioselected').add(this);
        $('#radioselected').after(this);
    }
});
```

so any radio clicked in the "swap" row should switch positions with the radio in the first row with the id 'selectedradio'

Comment: Do you want to swap the radio buttons only, or the labels also?

Comment: labels aswell, the whole code really for that element, just in case the user wants to click something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a delegate instead of binding the event on the radio buttons directly. That way the radio buttons that are swapped into the div will also work.

Use the `closest` method to get the label around the radio buttons.

Remove the id from the radio button that you swap with, and add it to the selected radio button.

Use the `after` method to move the label into the second list next to the selected one, then use `prependTo` to move the label with the selected radio button into the first list.

You have some invalid HTML code that makes the rows swap place. Change `<td><tr>` to `<tr><td>`.

```
$("div.radiogroup2").on("click", ":radio", function () {
  var l = $(this).closest('label');
  var r = $('#radioselected');
  r.removeAttr('id');
  l.after(r.closest('label'));
  $(this).attr('id', 'radioselected');
  l.prependTo('.radiogroup1');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DCC66/16/

Comment: lol so elegant, the way you wizards spin your code, thank you so much.